# Shared ApllicationContext throws BeanFactory not initialized or already closed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have two apllications, Main Spring Boot application and its library also created in Spring Boot. The main project is in need to use Components defined in library and library need to obtain ApplicationContext from Main project.

- **A** This is spring boot application which contains application context and it is deployed to Tomcat
- **B** This application is packed as jar file and used as maven dependency in application **B**

Two questions here:

1. **A** hold application context and registers all beans from application **B** (Can I use @Import or @ImportResource here?)
2. **B** uses application context from **A** (I have tried to inject it using ApplicationContextAware but it deos not seem to work)

The problem is that with solution described above application **A** so main app throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1032)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4732)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5396)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't. The library needs to be a regular jar that is included in your main project. You shouldn't have multiple contexts.

Comment: There is one ApplicationContext. It is in Main/Parent app. I need to inject/get it somehow in the library.

Comment: No you don't. The library shold be a regular jar, that is part of the main (or vice/versa).

Comment: It will simply defy the purpose of `ApplicationContext`. Also, it isn't possible to access that object in a different application.

Comment: No it won't defy the purpose of the application context. You shouldn't be sharing beans between different applications as that will only lead to weird issues with threading, classloading etc. You should define the beans in  your own context.

Comment: I know it but that is how requirements looks so I am searching for any hint.

Comment: The requirement is wrong and will only lead to issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum *You shouldn't be sharing beans between different applications*. It turns out that Spring developers do share the beans between applications. I think this topic is fairly arguable.

Comment: That is only valid in an EAR, with ejbs and wars inside the same EAR. Which make them part of the same application. If you want to "share" between indepently deployed apps, you should use remoting NOT beans from one app to another. This will only lead to classloading issues (each war has its own classloader), threading/sharing etc. issues. So don't.

Comment: @M.Deinum Remoting in this century? Oh common. As I said that this thing is arguable unless the application is a microservice.

Comment: It isn't argueable it is just wrong. The library you ar sharing classes for/from both apps need to know the classes already. (Else you cannot do a lookup), which basically binds both applications together at the binary level. Even if you have the same class it isn't the same class because they are in different classloaders. You could put the jar in the shared lib of tomcat, but now you need to deploy the jar and both apps on update of that jar. Hence you are binding things you shouldnt be binding. And yes remoting, for which spring has nice support or you could be calling an endpoit.

Comment: @M.Deinum I don't have enough time for this. RMI is just way too much for native calls, did you even took into account of the overheads? Let's talk about binding. Well, things can be bound when it is required. RMI is also a binding/dependency. Don't think that reputation on this site matters, it just means you have more free time than me.

Comment: I said *remoting* I didn't say RMI... RMI is one solution but you can also use http (see the Spring remoting parts). The point is you shouldn't share beans between applications (in this case deployment units) as t hat will lead to all sorts of weird issues and you certainly don't want to bind together 2 (or more) applications on the binary level (java classes).

Answer (score 1):

You can `@ComponentScan` the another project(B) for getting the beans into main project(A):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.example.B"})
class MyApplication {}
```

I don't think you can use the `ApplicationContext` from one project in another.